# Geolocation working on localhost but not on remote server

Tags: geolocation, google-geocoder

I have quite a few scripts that calculate latitude and longitude and they all work on localhost, however they all only work RANDOMLY on a PARTICULAR remote server. What could possibly cause this? Could it be the remote server? It is hard to believe that all those scripts are corrupted.

Comment: Please share which server variable you used to get the visitor IP address.

Comment: Hey, the script grabs the address (not IP) and then converts it to lon and lat.

Comment: I afraid without source codes and configuration of remote server, no much help can be done here.